# I'm having trouble with if/else conditional element selection. I get good output but fails in browser()

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble with a bit of code that is related to conditional element selection. This code is part of a function and runs properly to generate output, but it fails in the browser() mode if I use it to take a closer look at what intermediate values the function generates. There are 5 categories I am dealing with

```
if(length(Circuit)==1){
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/74820
  }else if (length(Circuit)>=2 && length(Circuit)<=5){
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/69875
  }else if (length(Circuit)==6){
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/65575
  }else if (length(Circuit)==7){
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/63210
  }else {
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/60845
  }
```

For context, I'm dealing with 3 yr of judicial data. Each county has data. The function this is inside aggregates these data based on what circuit (district) they are in. Once I get to the part in which it used a certain value as a denominator based on the # of counties in the circuit (district), it gives this error when I deal with a circuit that is 5 counties long:

```
debug at #2: if (length(Circuit) >= 2 && length(Circuit) <= 5) {
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/69875
} else if (length(Circuit) == 6) {
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/65575
} else if (length(Circuit) == 7) {
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/63210
} else {
    Circuit_FTE <- Circuit_Minutes/60845
}
```

This piece of the overall function will not generate a Circuit_FTE value. I have tried making all of them if_else, I have tried making all of them if. I'm dumbfounded. When I run the entire huge function, this part works, but this above happens when I try to use browser() to see a step-by-step approach.

Thank you

I am expected to see this give me the Circuit_FTE value in the "browser()" mode when browser is used for the overall function.

Comment: As [mentioned on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/14th76b/comment/jr2txeq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), show where you call browser(). Refer [mcve]

Comment: Curious what your data looks like that would motivate conditions based on `length(Circuit)` instead of `Circuit`.